# HTML5 Summary tag in editor

Tags: tags, editor, wysiwyg

I'd like to use the summary tag to summarise the content of a post, but I'm facing a couple of issues doing that:

1. There isn't an option for it in the wysiwyg  - how can I add elements to the format dropdown?
2. Wordpress strips out the element when the editor loads, so saving the page again removes the tag. How can I whitelist `<summary>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$allowed_tags` global. Add the following to your functions.php file.

```
global $allowedtags;
$allowedtags['summary'] = array('class' => array());
```

Add more attributes within the array similar to the `class` element. You can learn more on Otto's post [here](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/):